# ASP.NET MVC - "Cannot await 'method group'", and "namespace name 'ASPNETCoreWebApplication' could not be found"

Tags: asp.net-mvc, namespaces, method-group

Having an issue where `return View(await _context.Reviews.ToListAsync);` gives the following error: `Cannot await 'method group'`

I'm lead to believe that to use the `return View(await _context.Reviews.ToListAsync);` statement, I need to use `using ASPNETCoreWebApplication.data` (hence my inclusion of it), but  it returns an error: `The type or namespace 'ASPNETCoreWebApplication' could not be found [...]`.

If I remove `using <project_name>data`, there is the same error as above for `ApplicationDbContext` in `HomeController.cs`)

Below is my `HomeController.cs`:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;
using ASPNETCoreWebApplication.Data; // "The type or namespace 'ASPNETCoreWebApplication' could not be found [...]"
using <project_name>.Data;
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;

namespace <project_name>.Controllers
{
    public class HomeController : Controller
    {
        private readonly ApplicationDbContext _context;

        public HomeController(ApplicationDbContext context)
        {
            _context = context;
        }

        public async Task<IActionResult> Reviews()
        {
            // "Cannot await 'method group'"
            return View(await _context.Reviews.ToListAsync);
        }

        public IActionResult Error()
        {
            return View();
        }
    }
}
```

In case it may be relevant, here is my `Reviews.cs` Model:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace <project_name>.Models
{
    public class Reviews
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string Date { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public string Heading { get; set; }
        public string Restaurant { get; set; }
        public string Comment { get; set; }
        public int Rating { get; set; }
        public int Agree { get; set; }
        public int Disagree { get; set; }
    }
}
```

In `HomeController.cs`,

Comment: `.ToListAsync()`

Comment: You forgot the parentheses: `ToListAsync()`

Comment: Well don't I feel like a fool... Thank you both :)

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Don't make the rookie error of forgetting parentheses:

```
public async Task<IActionResult> Reviews()
        {
            return View(await _context.Reviews.ToListAsync());
        }
```